# How to extract video's file volume information using FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

We need to extract the volume information for every second from a video file in order to produce a graphical representation of volume changes during the video progress.
I'm trying to use `FFMPEG` with audio filter but I get stucked in how to extract the volume information for every second (or frame) and then export this information to some report file.

Thanks in advance.